# How to apply CIVignette as if CIImage were square?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I have a 1080x1920 `CIImage` and wish to apply `CIVignette` as if the image were square (to mimic a camera lens).

I'm new to CoreImage and am wondering how to temporarily change the `extent` of my `CIImage` to 1920x1920. (But I'm not sure if this is needed at all.)

I could copy-paste two narrow slivers of the original image left and right and `CICrop` afterwards, but this seems hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `clampedToExtent` (which causes the image to repeat its border pixels infinitely) and `cropped` to make the image square. Then you can apply the vignette and crop the result back to the original extent:

```
// "crop" to square, placing the image in the middle
let longerSize = max(inputImage.extent.width, inputImage.extent.height)
let xOffset = (longerSize - inputImage.extent.width) / 2.0
let yOffset = (longerSize - inputImage.extent.height) / 2.0
let squared = inputImage.clampedToExtent().cropped(to: CGRect(x: -xOffset, y: -yOffset, width: longerSize, height: longerSize))

// apply vignette
let vignetteFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIVignette")!
vignetteFilter.setValue(squared, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
vignetteFilter.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
vignetteFilter.setValue(1.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
let withVignette = vignetteFilter.outputImage!

// crop back to original extent
let output = withVignette.cropped(to: inputImage.extent)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot, again, Frank! (I've also upped a few of your other answers ;-)  Do you know any online resources or books about CoreImage and filtering that go through things step-by-step?

Comment: There is a (somewhat outdated but Apple endorsed) book by FlexMonkey on Apple Books: https://books.apple.com/de/book/core-image-for-swift/id1073029980?l=en

Comment: Otherwise it's probably still best to study the (outdated) Core Image Programming guide and translate the old Obj-C code in your head: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html

Comment: For checking what system filters are available and their documentation, check out the excellent https://cifilter.io. There is also an app for that that lets you play with the filters on device.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that free iBook! I already use cifilter.io + app, handy to have (but a bad UI).